# H2 dump tables content only

Tags: h2

I try to backup the tables content of a H2 DB.

I run : `SCRIPT  TO '/opt/data/2019-10-10_tr.sql' TABLE EVENEMENT, PASSAGE, COURSE, LIGNE` but the file generated contains some information like :

```
SET DB_CLOSE_DELAY -1;         
;              
CREATE USER IF NOT EXISTS SA SALT '7ab09337026fac20' HASH    'c...fa387' ADMIN;            
CREATE SEQUENCE PUBLIC.HIBERNATE_SEQUENCE START WITH 5664;     
CREATE MEMORY TABLE PUBLIC.COURSE(
...
```

Which I don't want (that's why I wanted to dump only the tables). I don't want them because when I run `RUNSCRIPT FROM '/opt/data/2019-10-10_tr.sql'` I have an exception :

```
CREATE SEQUENCE PUBLIC.HIBERNATE_SEQUENCE START WITH 5664 [90035-197]: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Sequence "HIBERNATE_SEQUENCE" already exists; SQL statement:
CREATE SEQUENCE PUBLIC.HIBERNATE_SEQUENCE START WITH 5664 [90035-197]
at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:357)
```

And I have this exception because the database is initialized by ddl : `<property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create-drop" />`

I don't wish to change this ; basically by saving only database content and restore it in an existing db : it should work, isn't it ? So the question is what is wrong with my SCRIPT syntax though it doesn't save the tables content only ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`SCRIPT` command is not designed to export only the data, it is designed to export the schema with or without the data. Currently there is no built-in command for that purpose.

You can try to add the ˙DROP˙ clause to this command to generate commands for dropping existing tables, but you still may have a problem with sequences and your tables will be redefined, so all changes in autogenerated schema will be lost.

You can filter out all non-`INSERT` commands from the script with your own code.

You can export the complete script and execute `DROP ALL OBJECTS` before `RUNSCRIPT` and overwrite everything with it.

Comment: `DROP ALL OBJECTS before RUNSCRIPT` : that's the good idea ! I don't know why I didn't think about it :( Thanks.